# Ubuntu limiting the internet bandwith

Tags: networking, internet, 19.04

Recently we have noticed that a few computers at work that use Ubuntu are having their internet speed limited.
We tried every troubleshooting method we could think of (more or less in this order):
- Restarted the affected computers,
- Changed the cables (including using a cable that provides the correct internet speed on other computers),
- Changed the switch settings for the affected computers,
- Changed the port in which the computer is connected to the switch,
- Changed most Ubuntu network settings

The only thing that changed the speed was using our office phone as a switch (connection became ISP -> Switch -> Phone -> Computer).

It's important to note that this issue affects just some of the computer running Ubuntu in the office. If the computer is running Windows it isn't affected.
Also important to note that only the download speed is affected, upload speeds are normal in all machines.

All connections are cabled. All machines running Ubuntu 19.04.

Attached to this post is a screenshot of an affected Ubuntu machine and another of a non-affected one, both taken almost at the same time with both machines running Chrome on Ubuntu 19.04.

Affected machine speed test
[image: Affected machine speed test]
Normal machine speed test:
[image: Normal machine speed test]

Comment: Do you have QoS enabled in your router?

Comment: status please...

Comment: Sorry, no we don't

Answer (score -1):

From my knowledge, this might be a problem with 19.04, I haven't encountered this problem on xubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 18.04. If you're using 19.04 as a normal computer and not a test station, or something like that, I highly suggest using 18.04, as 19.04 is not considered a stable build while 18.04 is LTS (Long Term Support). Unfortunately if this doesn't work, I'm not too sure what to do.